# Does Dexguard work for phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, dexguard

On this page http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard, it says that Dexguard encrypts assets. Will the phonegap app still work?

Answer (score 0):

DexGuard now comes with a sample that illustrates how to encrypt assets in a Cordova application.